# Umlauts in ISO-8859-1 encoded website

Tags: http, go, encoding

My very simple code snippet:

```
import "net/http"
import "io"
import "os"

func main() {
  resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com")
  if err == nil {
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
  }
}
```

When `example.com` is `charset=iso-8859-1` encoded my output is faulty. Umlauts for example are not displayed correctly:

`Hällo Wörld  --> H?llo W?rld`

Whats a good solution to display umlauts correctly??

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/VudK_05B62k/1tWuGCw1FgAJ;context-place=forum/golang-nuts) is relevant.

Comment: Or set your terminal to iso-8859-1 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package [golang.org/x/net/html/charset](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset) to determine the encoding of the website, and also create a reader that converts the content to UTF-8.

Below is a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com")
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    r, err := charset.NewReader(resp.Body, resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the detailed code snippet!